# MAAS error on deleting a subnet

Tags: networking, maas

I'm trying to delete a subnet in the MAAS web interface and I get this error:

```
insert or update on table "maasserver_staticipaddress" violates foreign key constraint "maasserver_st_subnet_id_4150751b40bb532_fk_maasserver_subnet_id" DETAIL: Key (subnet_id)=(1) is not present in table "maasserver_subnet".
```

MAAS has also suddenly stopped finding any of my servers on the network and has since been completely unable to deploy them.

**Edit:** bug report filed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1642091

Comment: Please file a bug at http://launchpad.net/maas. Include your MAAS logs so the MAAS team can take a look at the issue that is occurring.

Comment: Added! https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1642091